# Can't get ReCAPTCHA to work (or even display!)

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'm sure it's simple but I can't see it :)

I'm trying to add a reCAPTCHA into the code for an existing site with a little contact form.

I have the keys from Google (censored in the examples of course) but I can't even get it to display the CAPTCHA, let alone anything test if the filtering is working.

I've added the reCAPTCHA code into the page:

index.html:

```
form name="f1" method="post" action="mail2.php" onsubmit="return verify();">
<p><label>Your Name <span>(*)</span></label><input type="text" name="name" /></p>
<p><label>Your Email</label><input type="text" name="email" /></p>
<p><label>Your Phone No: <span>(*)</span></label><input type="text" name="phone" /></p>
<p><label>Other messages</label><textarea name="messages" rows="" cols=""></textarea>    </p>
<?php
   require_once('recaptchalib.php');
   $publickey = "6LdrxxxxxxxxxxxxxxJr"; // you got this from the signup page
      echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
    ?>

            <p style="padding-right:36px; float:right;"><input name="" type="image" src="images/submit_btn.png" /></p>
            </form>
```

And in the mail2.php

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "6LxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxqZYiH";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification



require_once 'mailer/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
----followed by the standard PHPMailer content----
```

The index page just displays as standard with no CAPTCHA section displayed, trying to send an email results in failure with some PHP code displayed.

I'd really appreciate if someone with a mind larger than mine who eats & breathes reCAPTCHA could cast their eye, laugh & point at where I've gone wrong. :)

Looking to be educated rather than just a fix. My skills lie in content rather than coding I'm afraid.

(And how do I insert a code block in the editor? Surely don't have to indent each line by 4 spaces individually?)

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help because I have it working farther than you, but I need help on this subject too.
To begin, you need this line of code in your html header (before the `</head>` tag:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?fallback=true" async defer></script>
```

Then in the body of your html, and somewhere inside of your form (between your `<form>` ... `</form>` tags) you need the following code:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="....your site key here...."></div>
```

Then in your PHP processing file (the file that your form posts to and receives the form variables you need the following code:

```
$response_string = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$secret_key = "...put in your secret key here...";
$resp = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret_key&response=$response_string");

if($resp != '{ "success": true }')
{   $problem = "failedreCAPTCHA";
    header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/...pagetohandlefailedentry...php?problem=$problem");
    die('Sorry, you entered the wrong value in the Human CAPTCHA challenge. Please try again.'); 
}
```

This code works great except for the "if($resp != '{ "success": true }')" part of it. Because the variable $resp get filled with from google is "{ "success": true }" which turns out to be a JSON object and I don't know how to test for "true" with PHP and a JSON object.
So... someone, please help.

Comment: This does not really provide an answer to the question. If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I might recommend adding a link to whatever sources your using. This would help direct the original poster to some more helpful and complete information since you mention being unsure about a certain aspect of your answer.

Comment: My response DOES answer some of his question...he asked "Can't get ReCAPTCHA to work (or even display!)" My offered solution DOES WORK to get reCAPTCHA to display.
I'm really disappointed in you "honk" and you "philtune". Duncan Reid asks a question several months ago, and gets no response from anyone. Then I come along and try to help, and what do I get in return?...
So instead of either of you contributing anything useful or valuable to answer the question, you just crap on me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sources for my responses:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: Thanks Brook, that's interesting & shows just how deficient the instructions I was reading were!

That makes sense & will be remembered for next time.

In this instance I ended up ripping the code out & using a ready built mailer (with inbuilt CAPTCHA) which worked perfectly - there's always a way round things! :)

Thanks for posting the info though, it'll help others & I'll remember it for nexttime!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working for me, using Google's new "no Captcha reCaptcha". This largely builds off of Brook's answer, but includes the ip, parses the json, and tests for success.

```
<?php
  $gSecret = "...put in your secret key here...";
  $gResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
  $gRemoteIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $gResponse = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$gSecret&response=$gResponse&remoteip=$gRemoteIp");
  $resp = json_decode($gResponse);

  if (!$resp->success) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error-codes . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  }
?>
```